# Can you pass an object key as a param? - Svelte/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key, svelte

I'm using Svelte and my component wants to take in an array of objects and a specific key. However it doesn't want to read the key when it is a variable. This is what I've tried so far.

```
  export let data = [];
  export let key;
  function cleanUp(data, key) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let d = data[i].key;
      newArray.push(d);
    }
  }
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If the `key` variable contains a string, you can access an object's property with that name with `object[key]`.

In your example:

```js
let d = data[i][key];
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thank you, glad it was so simple

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer :)